# How can I write out to the screen in Android what I get in an UDP package?

Tags: java, android, udp

I would like to get some help in Android programming.

I have a little program which receives UDP packages, and I try to write out the messages into a `TextView`, but it doesn't work. Do you have any idea what is the problem with this code? There isn't any red underline in the Android Studio, but when it gets a package, it either doesn't do anything or it crashes.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        UDPReciever();
    }

    public void UDPReciever(){
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    int port = 55777;
                    DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
                    byte[] receiveData = new byte[8];
                    byte[] sendData = new byte[8];

                    while(true)
                    {
                        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                        serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                        String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData());

                        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                        textView.setText(sentence);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: *it either doesn't do anything or it crashes.* ... well it is obvious  with such great error handling `catch (Exception e){

            }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the code to update the `TextView` is not executed on UI thread. To execute code on UI thread, the easiest way is to use `runOnUiThread()` method of the `Activity`, e.g.:

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        textView.setText(sentence);
    }
});
```